Problem with distributive conditional type
I am trying to create a conditional type AnimalLabel in TypeScript.
abstract class Animal {
    abstract readonly legCount: number;
}

class Monkey extends Animal {
    legCount: number = 2;
}

class Cow extends Animal {
    legCount: number = 4;
}

class Pirate extends Animal {
    legCount: number = 1;
}

export type AnimalLabel<T extends Animal> =
    T extends Monkey ? 'Monkey label' :
    T extends Pirate ? 'Pirate label' :
    T extends Cow ? 'Cow label' :
    never;

const label: AnimalLabel<Pirate> = 'Pirate label'; // Compiler complains about this line

The compiler gives this error: Type '"Pirate label"' is not assignable to type '"Monkey label"'.
What am I doing wrong?

Types in TypeScript are structural, not nominal. Your three classes are identical in structure, so Pirate extends Monkey is true.  If you don't want that, make sure your classes differ structurally, by (for example) adding different properties to each, as shown in this playground link. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate; if not, what am I missing?

@jcalz, I see your point. My actual use case differs a bit from the code I provided. I actually want the utility type (called AnimalLabel above) to return a class.
 T extends Monkey ? MonkeyDescriptor :
 T extends Pirate ? PirateDescriptor :
 T extends Cow ? CowDescriptor
 never;```
Is there any way to achieve this without making all Animal classes structurally different?

You'd need to [edit] to put such information in the question text as a [mre] (so you'd need to declare your XDescriptor types). I don't know why whether you return a class or a string would make a difference. You simply must make the classes differ structurally. There might be ways to make that less cumbersome, but the answer to your question is "use structural types, not nominal types". Shall I write that answer or do you think I'm missing something?

As explained in the comment, you can't distinguish types with the same structure.
If the number of animal classes becomes big the conditional type is hard to maintain. To avoid duplication of the label for each class instance I would suggest to use a static property:
Playground
abstract class Animal {
    abstract readonly legCount: number;
    static readonly label: string;
}

class Monkey extends Animal {
    static readonly label = 'Monkey label';
    legCount: number = 2;
}

class Cow extends Animal {
    static readonly label = 'Cow label';
    legCount: number = 4;
}

class Pirate extends Animal {
    static readonly label = 'Pirate label';
    legCount: number = 1;
}

export type AnimalLabel<T extends typeof Animal> = T['label']

const label: AnimalLabel<typeof Pirate> = 'Pirate label';

With this approach (as mentioned in the comments, I didn't look so far) you could assign labels directly:
const label = Pirate.label;

Given that an instance property is usually more useful I'd rather do the label as a prototype readonly prop:
abstract class Animal {
    abstract readonly legCount: number;
    readonly label: string;
}

class Monkey extends Animal {
    get label(){ return 'Monkey label'; }
    legCount: number = 2;
}


So you're switching to typeof Pirate instead of Pirate? I guess that might satisfy the use case but it's not clear from the question.

@jcalz i'm silly not being able to infer the class type from the instance type ‍♂️ . if you could help i'd appreciate

At this point you could simply do const label = Pirate.label.  and nuke the whole AnimalLabel util.
